# What nodejs library is most like jQuery's deferreds?

Tags: jquery, node.js, asynchronous

I've become a skilled user of jQuery's new and amazing Deferred module, and as I'm easing into using more of Node.js, I find myself wanting something exactly like it in much of my Node.js programming: callbacks that block until a collection of promises devolves to resolved, with the freedom to add to the array on-the-fly as the task grows in complexity-- such as when one processes a tree of data, the size of which is not known at the start of the task.

But `node-fibers` requires a whole new executable, `Q()`'s interface is just damned confusing, and `node-step` only seems to handle single-task synchronizations.

Has someone just ported jQuery's Deferreds to a node-ready form?  It doesn't seem that unlikely, nor does it seem that Deferreds is dependent upon DOM-available features, but I haven't found a server-side equivalent.

Comment: Not like jQuery deferred, but [asyn](https://github.com/limeblack/asyn) is certainly simple.  Could you give some examples of the syntax you are looking for.  Thanks ;)

Comment: [jquery-deferred-for-node](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-deferred-for-node) uses jQuery's tests, can't get much closer than that ;)  (also posted as answer below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This node library looks quite similar in functionality to jQuery's Deferred:

https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise

Answer (score 23):

If you want the same API, there's nothing stopping you from using jQuery itself under Node. Just `npm install jquery`, then:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var deferred = $.Deferred();
```

Comment: jquery module is the same as jquery for browser ? or this is clean version of it (without browser API)

Comment: This doesn't work with jQuery 2.1.1. jQuery for node now requires you instantiate it with a window + document before use (even for functionality like deferred objects).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can get any closer than [jQuery deferred lib for nodeJS](https://github.com/zzdhidden/node-jquery-deferred).

Comment: No, but you can do better.  I'm looking into iced-coffeescript right now.  Wow.

Answer (score 3):

This wasn't around when the question was asked, but according to the readme it uses (and passes) the jquery tests.  It appears to be exactly identical minus the (jQuery||$). prefix.

https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-deferred-for-node

Answer (score 1):

This nodejs module is CommonJS compliant.

https://github.com/cujojs/when

Answer (score 0):

Googling: deferred for nodejs

Gave me: https://github.com/felixge/node-deferred

Though not exactly what you are looking for, is moderately close.  I find that the callback chaining is fairly natural, though deeply nested chains can be a bit difficult to keep up with.

Searching for: promise nodejs  lead me down a path of more interesting results...

- https://github.com/willconant/flow-js
- https://github.com/creationix/conductor

Both of which are probably much closer to what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Note that "node-deferred" seems to be unmaintained. The last commit was in 2009.

Comment: Deferreds in javascript are pretty straightforward.  Once an implementation is built, there are no features to add... hence the lack of updates.

Answer (score -1):

This node library contains jquery 1.8.2 deferred class.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-deferred

npm install jquery-deferred