# About Node's code style

Tags: javascript, node.js, coding-style, deferred

**EDIT**

thx to all the answers, 
and finally I decide to use some tools like [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step),

all I need is "flow control" and don't want any thing else which may slow down the performance (I don't know how much exactly it would effect or the effect just can be ignored).

So I just create a little tool for flow control:

line.js

```
/**
 * Create the "next" function
 * 
 * @param {Array} tasks 
 * @param {Number} index
 * @param {Number} last
 */
var next = function(tasks, index, last) {

    if (index == last) {

        return tasks[index + 1];
    }
    else {

        return function(data) {

            var nextIndex = index + 1;
            tasks[nextIndex](next(tasks, nextIndex, last), data);
        };
    }
};

/**
 * Invoke functions in line.
 */
module.exports = function() {

    var tasks = arguments,
        last = tasks.length - 2;

    tasks[0](next(tasks, 0, last));
};
```

usage:

```
var line = require("line.js");
line(function(next) {

    someObj.find(function(err, docs) {

        // codes
        next(docs);
    });
}, function(next, docs) {

    // codes
});
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT END**

As all know,
Node's built-in or third-part modules often provides async API,
and using "callback" function for dealing the results.

It's cool but sometimes would code like this:

```
                   //some codes
              }
         }
    }
}
```

codes like this are hard to read.

I know "deferred" library can solve such problem, 
Is there any good "deferred" module for Node?
And How is the performance if I code Node with "deferred"?

Comment: it's default code style... how that could be harder to read? don't get it.

Comment: You don't need a deferred, you need to use control flow properly. Also know as learn to utilize callbacks effectively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* a large problem with Node-based code; you frequently grow "callback pyramids".  There are several approaches to dealing with the problem:

**Code style:**

Use this annoyance as an opportunity to break your code into bite sized chunks.  It means you're likely going to have a proliferation of tiny named funcs - that's probably just fine, though!  You might also find more opportunities for reuse.

**Flow-control Libraries**

There are exactly 593.72 billion flow control libraries out there.  Here's some of the more popular ones:

- [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step) super basic serial & parallel flow management.
- [seq](https://github.com/substack/node-seq) is a heavier but more feature-full flow control library.
- There's plenty more.  Search [the npm registry](http://search.npmjs.org/) for "flow" and "flow control" (sorry, doesn't appear to be linkable)

**Language Extensions**

There are several attempts to provide a more synchronous-feeling syntax on top of JavaScript (or CoffeeScript), often based on the concepts behind the [tame paper](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~max/docs/tame.pdf).

- [TameJS](http://tamejs.org/) is the OkCupid team's answer to this.
- [IcedCoffeeScript](http://maxtaco.github.com/coffee-script/) they've also ported TameJS over CoffeeScript as a fork.
- [streamline.js](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs) is very similar to TameJS.
- [StratifiedJS](http://onilabs.com/stratifiedjs) is a heavier approach to the problem.

This route is a deal-breaker for some:

- It's not standard JavaScript; if you are building libraries/frameworks/etc, finding help will be more difficult.
- Variable scope can behave in unexpected ways, depending on the library.
- The generated code can be difficult to debug & match to the original source.

**The Future:**

The node core team is very aware of the problem, and are also working on lower level components to help ease the pain.  It looks like they'll be introducing [a basic version of domains](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/eVBOYiI_O_A/1ShfZZvb_4QJ) in v0.8, which provide a way of rolling up error handling (avoiding the common `return err if err` pattern, primarily).

This should start to lay a great foundation for cleaner flow control libraries, and start to pave the way for a more consistent way of dealing with callback pyramids.  There's too much choice out there right now, and the community isn't close to agreeing on even a handful of standards yet.

**References:**

- [Mixu's Node book has an awesome chapter](http://book.mixu.net/ch7.html) on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of "deferred libraries". Have a look there http://eirikb.github.com/nipster/#promise and there http://eirikb.github.com/nipster/#deferred. To pick one, it's only a matter of style & simplicity :)

Comment: So you mean there are no performance issue on using "deferred"?

Comment: I never told so :) I think deferred don't performs *that* well than "native code" but the impact is somewhat small. But I have no metrics to tell yes or no this could be an issue

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't like that, there's always the alternative of using **named functions**, which will reduce the indentation.

Instead of

```
setTimeout(function() {
  fs.readFile('file', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
  })
}, 200);
```

You can do this:

```
function dataHandler(err, data)
{
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
}

function getFile()
{
  fs.readFile('file', dataHandler);
}

setTimeout(getFile, 200);
```

The same thing, no nesting.

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries that may be useful in some scenarios, but as a whole you won't be excited after using them for everything.

According to the slowness issues. Since node.js is async, the wrapped functions are not such a big performance consumer.

You could look here for deferred-like library

https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise

Also this question is very similar

[What nodejs library is most like jQuery's deferreds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588581/what-nodejs-library-is-most-like-jquerys-deferreds)

And as a final bonus I suggest you take a look at [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). It is a language, which compiles to javascript and has more beautiful syntax, since the function braces are removed

Comment: Yep, but it surely makes it easier for reading. Of course it's a matter of opinion !

Comment: I know CoffeeScript and I think it's a little better than original JS codes in "spaghetti" situation. I always worried about performance issue on "deferred", so I decides not to use it.

Comment: Hum I don't think so. CoffeScript or not you still have a function which receive a callback as argument which receive a callback as argument which receive a callback as argument which receive a callback as argument which... OMG **recursion** ! But I agree with the rest of your answer :)

Comment: @Kelvin what kind of *issues* are you worried about ?

Comment: @pomeh That's what CS is ... just an elegant solution for your eye ;)

Comment: well... that's right, it's only another (light) syntax, where deferred are another way to think about it

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to use the async.js library as it offers a few different options on how to execute  the code