# How can I call multiple asynchronous javascript functions in sequence?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to call the following functions sequentially, but they don't necessarily return in the correct order.

I then learned about asynchronous functions which can be called sequentially using "callbacks".

How can I make these functions execute in sequence using callbacks?

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/search_data.php?title='+title+'&run=annotations&jsoncallback=?', function(r1){
    $.each(make_all_titles3(r1), function (i,v) {
        $vpl.append(v);     
    });
});

$.getJSON('http://localhost/search_data.php?title='+title+'&run=Link&jsoncallback=?', function(r2){
    $.each(make_all_titles3(r2), function (i,v) {
        $vpl.append(v);     
    });
});

$.getJSON('http://localhost/search_data.php?title='+title+'&user='+user+'&run=bookmarks&jsoncallback=?', function(r3){
    $.each(make_all_titles3(r3), function (i,v) {
        $vpl.append(v);     
    });
});

$vpl.append('<div>Related Terms</div>');

$.getJSON('http://localhost/context-search.php?title='+title+'&jsoncallback=?', function(r4){
    $.each(make_all_titles3(r4), function (i,v) {
        $vpl.append(v);     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be simply nesting the calls. Scroll down for a clean and readable solution.

```
function _process(r) {
    $.each(make_all_titles3(r), function (i, v) {
        $vpl.append(v);
    });
}

$.getJSON('http://localhost/search_data.php?title=' + title + '&run=annotations&jsoncallback=?', function (r) {
    _process(r);
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/search_data.php?title=' + title + '&run=Link&jsoncallback=?', function (r) {
        _process(r);
        $.getJSON('http://localhost/search_data.php?title=' + title + '&user=' + user + '&run=bookmarks&jsoncallback=?', function (r) {
            _process(r);
            $vpl.append('<div>Related Terms</div>');
            $.getJSON('http://localhost/context-search.php?title=' + title + '&jsoncallback=?', function (r) {
                _process(r);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Now the clean and readable one, using the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library:

```
var load = [
    { url: 'http://localhost/search_data.php?title=' + title + '&run=annotations&jsoncallback=?', before: null },
    { url: 'http://localhost/search_data.php?title=' + title + '&run=Link&jsoncallback=?', before: null },
    { url: 'http://localhost/search_data.php?title=' + title + '&user=' + user + '&run=bookmarks&jsoncallback=?', before: null },
    { url: 'http://localhost/context-search.php?title=' + title + '&jsoncallback=?', before: function() { $vpl.append('<div>Related Terms</div>'); } }
];

async.forEachSeries(load, function(item, next) {
    if(item.before) {
        item.before();
    }
    $.getJSON(item.url, function(r) {
        $.each(make_all_titles3(r), function (i, v) {
            $vpl.append(v);
        });
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: when i tried to run the above code, it gives an error of **async is not defined**. what should i do now!!

Comment: As I said, you need the async library and include it on your page. `<script src="https://raw.github.com/caolan/async/master/dist/async.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

See my question here: [About Node's code style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278721/about-nodes-code-style) 
And I provide a helper function for making embedded callbacks called in line. 
It works both for NodeJS and browser JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
ajaxcall1(parameter, function() {
    ajaxcall2(parameter, function() {
        ajaxcall3(parameter, function() {
            alert("lol");
        };
    };
});
```

Explanation: call the 2nd ajax call when the first returns its result and the 3d when the 2nd returns.

Answer (score -1):

use ajax async false option

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
    // put your three get methods here
$.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
```

NOTE: this will halts your dynamic page functionality until your total code block's execution completes

Comment: I presume the downvotes are because the OP asked about how to achieve his/her aim with callbacks, but the async option will also make the functions execute sequentially, so I think this answer is just fine. (You might want to make clear that you’re offering an alternative solution to callbacks.)

Comment: `async: false` is almost never "fine" (unless used in an on[before]unload event).