# A script translatable to JavaScript with callback-hell automatic avoider

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, dom-events

I'm looking for "translator" for JavaScript like already is CoffeScript, which will be work for example with `forEach` (inspired by Groovy)

```
myArray.forEach() -> val, idx {
   // do something with value and idx
}
```

translate to JavaScript:

```
myArray.forEach(function(val, idx){
   // do something with value and idx
});
```

or something more usefull...

```
function event(cb){
  foo()-> err, data1;
  bar(data1)-> err, data2;      
  cb(data2);
}
```

the method are encapsulated:

```
function event(cb){
  foo(function(err,data1){
    bar(data1, function(err, data2) {
       cb(data2);
    });
  });
}
```

I want ask if similar "compiler" to JavaScript like this even better already doesn't exists?

What would be super cool... my code in nodejs looks mostly like this :-)

```
function dealer(cb){
  async.parallel([
    function(pcb){
      async.watterfall([function(wcb){
              first(function(a){ wcb(a); });
          }, function(a, wcb){
              thirt(a, function(c){ wcb(c); });
              fourth(a, function(d){ 
                // dealing with “a” as well and nobody care my result
              });
          }], 
        function(err, array_with_ac){
          pcb(array_with_ac);
        });
      }, function(pcb){
            second(function(b){ pcb(b);});
      }], function(err, data){
         cb(data[0][0]+data[1]+data[0][1]); // dealing with “a” “b” and “c” not with “d”
    });
  }
```

but, look how **beautiful** and **readable** the code could be:

```
function dealer(cb){
  first() -> a;
  second() -> b;
  third(a) -> c; // dealing with “a”     
  fourth(a) -> d; // dealing with “a” as well and nobody care about my result    
  cb(a+b+c); // dealing with “a” “b” and “c” not with “d”
}
```

*yes this is ideal case when the translator auto-decide, method need to be run as parallel and method need be call after finish another method. I can imagine it's works*

Please, do you know about something similar?

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19742602/1768303

Comment: http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/ there's always a risk of a custom programming language and extensions to end up unmaintained, and then you'll likely regret your choice. Better choice is to embrace the platform you've chosen, and make sure that you've chosen it for the right reasons.

Comment: Thank you for answer, the ice-coffee-script looks nice, but i actually don't like the coffee-script syntax, i read the nodejs comming with yeald and * in next version so it will be better just embrace the javascript and wait a while;-)

Comment: Consider using promises or generators (latest node), I recommend generators.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Promises (here is [an implementation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q))? It's plain Javascript so you won't change the syntax as CoffeeScript does but promises allow you to deal with the *"I want to use a, b and c but not d"* case in an elegant fashion.

Another possibility is to use [`async.auto`](https://github.com/caolan/async#autotasks-callback), which will execute asynchronous functions and determine the best order depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically looking for a solution to the async 'problem', you might want to take a look at [Streamline](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs).